# Variable of union type causes error in switch statement

Tags: javascript, typescript, switch-statement, union-types

Consider we have a union type that represents one of three different string values.

```
type Animal = 'bird' | 'cat' | 'dog';
```

Now I would like to create a dog and check what kind of animal it is to create the correct noise it performs.

```
let oscar: Animal = 'dog';

switch (oscar) {
  case 'bird':
    console.log('tweet');
    break;
  case 'cat':
    console.log('meow');
    break;
  case 'dog':
    console.log('bark');
    break;
}
```

This code will result in a TypeScript error: `Type '"bird"' is not comparable to type '"dog"'.ts(2678)` (analog with cat). However, if I use an explicit type cast on the variable `oscar`, it works without problems:

```
switch (oscar as Animal) {
  case 'bird':
    ...
  case 'cat':
    ...
  case 'dog':
    ...
}
```

Can you please explain to me why the first two switch statements fail if I use an explicit value for `oscar`?

I could understand the error if I declared Oscar as a constant: `const oscar = 'dog';`, because in that case it would always be a dog and nothing else. However, just imagine for a moment that Oscar could become a cat if a wizard would perform a certain spell:

```
let oscar: Animal = 'dog';

while(true) {
  switch (oscar) {
  case 'bird':
    ...
  case 'cat':
    ...
  case 'dog':
    console.log('bark');

    // here comes the wizard
    if(wizard.performsSpell('makeOscarBecomeACat')) {
      oscar = 'cat';  // that should be valid, because oscar is of type Animal
    }

    break;
  }
}
```

Do I misunderstand something about the assignment of the variable `oscar`, or is this simply a TypeScript bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you might be misunderstanding is that TypeScript 2.0 and above has a feature called [control-flow based type analysis](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis), implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#8010](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010).  One of the effects of this feature is that

> An assignment (including an initializer in a declaration) of a value of type `S` to a variable of type `T` changes the type of that variable to *`T` narrowed by `S`* in the code path that follows the assignment. [...]  The type *`T` narrowed by `S`* is computed as follows: [...]  If `T` is a union type, the result is the union of each constituent type in `T` to which `S` is assignable.

That means the statement

```
let oscar: Animal = 'dog';
```

is interpreted as: "the variable `oscar` has the type `Animal`, a union type.  It has been assigned a value of the string literal type `"dog"`, so until it gets reassigned, we will treat the variable `oscar` as the type *`Animal` narrowed by `"dog"`*, which is just `"dog"`.

And therefore in your `switch`/`case` statement:

```
case 'bird': // error!
//   ~~~~~~ <-- Type '"bird"' is not comparable to type '"dog"'
```

You get the error about trying to compare a string literal `"bird"` to a string literal `"dog"`.  The compiler knows that the `'bird'` case is impossible because you have not reassigned `oscar` to something compatible with `'bird'`.

Even in your `wizard` case, the compiler understands that when it reaches the `switch`/`case` statement, `oscar` can only be `"cat"` or `"dog"` and not `"bird"`:

```
case 'bird': // error! 
//   ~~~~~~ <-- Type '"bird"' is not comparable to type '"cat" | "dog"'
```

---

This is all probably good news; the compiler is catching cases that can never happen.  For many situations these are genuine bugs.

If you want the compiler not to realize that `oscar` is definitely `"dog"` and only know that it's an `Animal` (as, say, a placeholder until you write code that makes it genuinely possible for it to be any member of `Animal`), you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) in the assignment itself:

```
let oscar: Animal = 'dog' as Animal;
```

Now all your other code will compile without error. You can even forget the annotation since it wasn't helping you:

```
let oscar = 'dog' as Animal;
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UDkAjBAJwBMcoAfXAYxWDMp2IHsBzHAbgCgpO0JgoTAM41CWXMzZQUQ2IlRounIQHcEwKgAsoACmGiAlFADe3KOZpDo+IqQBcZ806hUmcIUz4A6NKx05gFQh+HAMuZ2c8QggUAGtwp0trGjoHCMS3D29fFn8kCCYVUIT0qJj4xxcZa0kcNPSXTM8IHz98FEJY4srI6LiuAF9OTmIIKjQO6Fd3ATUALw7iOxMoSEIAMyZCJCEAZUg0NB0AD2WUOBADZbwmZvOoIc4VTQQ+XWBCAFcII1NnVXUWl0+g6vx6iWquAIJDq4PMAHp4V5kXCqlZqLRYQ0oIjkV5UUkJKwsdiMu5mq1cu1Ot1SU5EVBNBBoo18rJgEyoPNFqjnAh1rpuSQvGtNts9gcjjhULEIAB5EQdABCYyY+RgAGFMQYwXT0iCxNgcCkOOZeU4hnqoGV+pUhgMgA)

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much for the detailed explanation of *narrow union types*, a conception I didn't know before but which makes sense to me.